# Pycel not evaluating formula

Tags: python, pycel

I have a spreadsheet with two cells:

```
Value in cell A1 = NOW() = [the current date-time as an Excel serial]
Value in cell A2 = A1 - INT(A1) = [the current time as an Excel serial]
```

After loading the spreadsheet to Python using Pycel, I run the following code:

```
    for i in range(10):
        print(excel.evaluate('Sheet1!A1'))
        print(excel.evaluate('Sheet1!A2'))
        time.sleep(1)
```

As the time has changed by more than a second each time the code loops, the value in 'A1' and 'A2' should be changing each time. However, over the 10 loops the code always returns one value for each of A1 and A2. In other words, it is not re-evaluating each time the code loops.

I know it says in the Pycel readme that 'caching' is used to speed things up. I think my issue might be related to the caching used? Is there a way to 'force evaluate' so that I get the correct result each time?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(10):
    excel.recalculate()
    print(excel.evaluate('Sheet1!A1'))
    print(excel.evaluate('Sheet1!A2'))
    time.sleep(1)
```

This should do the trick.